# User-Defined Deduction Guides in C++20

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, type-deduction

I'm working with `std::variant` and `std::visit` using the ["overload" pattern](https://www.bfilipek.com/2019/02/2lines3featuresoverload.html) that looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

int main(void) {
  std::variant<int, float> var;
  auto fs = overloaded {
    [](int var) {std::cout << "var is int" << std::endl;},
    [](float var) {std::cout << "var is float" << std::endl;}
  };
  var = 0;
  std::visit(fs, var);
  var = 0.0f;
  std::visit(fs, var);
}
```

On cppreference, there's [an example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit#Example) that says:

```
// explicit deduction guide (not needed as of C++20)
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;
```

Why is this deduction guide no longer needed in C++20? Removing the type deduction guide causes the [compile to fail on all current compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/zjb6hE), but no one fully supports C++20 right now so that doesn't mean anything. Can anyone point me to the part of the spec that discusses this?

Comment: It does work on [gcc trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/za4W5z).

Comment: @cigien Thanks for pointing that out! I didn't doubt that the comment was correct, just trying to figure out what changed in C++20 to make this legal.

Comment: @nickelpro. [P2082R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2082r1.pdf). Support on upcoming gcc-11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This change was added by [P1021R4](https://wg21.link/p1021r4), specifically [P1816R0](https://wg21.link/p1816r0), which added support for class template argument deduction for aggregates.

The specific wording can be found in [[over.match.class.deduct]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct) which adds, basically, an implicit deduction guide for aggregates:

> In addition, if `C` is defined and its definition satisfies the conditions for an aggregate class ([dcl.init.aggr]) with the assumption that any dependent base class has no virtual functions and no virtual base classes, and the initializer is a non-empty *braced-init-list* or *parenthesized expression-list*, and there are no *deduction-guides* for `C`, the set contains an additional function template, called the aggregate deduction candidate, defined as follows.
> Let x1,…,xn be the elements of the *initializer-list* or *designated-initializer-list* of the *braced-init-list*, or of the *expression-list*.
> For each xi, let ei be the corresponding aggregate element of `C` or of one of its (possibly recursive) subaggregates that would be initialized by xi ([dcl.init.aggr]) if
>
> - brace elision is not considered for any aggregate element that has a dependent non-array type or an array type with a value-dependent bound, and
> - each non-trailing aggregate element that is a pack expansion is assumed to correspond to no elements of the initializer list, and
> - a trailing aggregate element that is a pack expansion is assumed to correspond to all remaining elements of the initializer list (if any).
>
> If there is no such aggregate element ei for any xi, the aggregate deduction candidate is not added to the set.
> The aggregate deduction candidate is derived as above from a hypothetical constructor C(T1,…,Tn), where
>
> - if ei is of array type and xi is a braced-init-list or string-literal, Ti is an rvalue reference to the declared type of ei, and
> - otherwise, Ti is the declared type of ei,
>
> except that additional parameter packs of the form Pj... are inserted into the parameter list in their original aggregate element position corresponding to each non-trailing aggregate element of type Pj that was skipped because it was a parameter pack, and the trailing sequence of parameters corresponding to a trailing aggregate element that is a pack expansion (if any) is replaced by a single parameter of the form Tn....

Basically, the deduction-guide that you had to write before:

```
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;
```

just falls out of the language now.

Comment: Neither of the linked proposals have the wording for deduction from pack expansion. That appears to have been proposed in [p2082r1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2082r1.pdf) section 4