# Visiting std::variant with lambdas in C++20

Tags: c++, lambda, variadic-templates, c++20, variant

Cppreference provides example usage of `std::visit` to access the active member of `std::variant` via lambda functions:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit

An abbreviated version of the example code:

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <variant>
 
// helper type for the visitor
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
// explicit deduction guide (not needed as of C++20)
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;
 
int main() 
{
    std::variant<int, long, double, std::string> v("hello");

    std::visit(overloaded {
        [](auto arg) { std::cout << arg << ' '; },
        [](double arg) { std::cout << std::fixed << arg << ' '; },
        [](const std::string& arg) { std::cout << std::quoted(arg) << ' '; },
    }, v);
}
```

The comment states that the explicit deduction guide is not needed as of C++20. With this in mind, how would this example code look with C++20 usage?

Simply omitting the explicit deduction guide from the example will not compile in GCC 10.2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [User-Defined Deduction Guides in C++20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62868708/user-defined-deduction-guides-in-c20) The linked question is exactly with the same example from the same cpp ref :-)

Comment: Wow! It most certainly does! Thank you for pointing that out. I have flagged my question as a duplicate.

Comment: I does compile with gcc trunk on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/oKx5xf).